# Remove all special consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Hopefully a simple one but I can't find any exact thread on SO for this particular instance:

If I have a string with multiple special characters in a row i.e `'this-is--a---string'` I want to remove all duplicate non alphanumeric characters with regex so it would end up as `'this-is-a-string'`

The closest i've found is `.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1')` but this removes duplicate letters rather than just special characters.

On a side note if anyone knows how to remove any non alphanumeric characters from the end of a string with regex then that would be really useful too!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should it only remove the same repeated character or any sequence of _special_ characters, eg `this-is-_a-_-_-_-_-string`? What the result for that string look like?

Comment: @Phil just the same repeated character i.e `--` or `$$$$` etc

Comment: For your bonus question, I'd just use a secondary _replace_... `.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+$/i, "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to collapse only repeated non alphanumeric characters, it should be enough to change your regex replacing the `.` character class with something that will negate the alphanumeric group `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

```js
subject = "a---------------bbbbbb6times_______@@@@@@";

var myregexp = /([^a-zA-Z0-9])\1+/mg;
result = subject.replace(myregexp, "$1");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `'mystring_'.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]$/mg,'');` to replace the last character of the string if it's not alphanumeric